# Inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation on the form
$$
C_1\frac{d}{dt}F(r, t) = C_2-C_3F(r, t)
$$
where $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are some constants. How is it possible for me to solve for $F$ in this case?

Comment: The first thought was yes, but then the solution will only make sense if you keep r fixed? As solving that differential equation will only depend on t explicitly. If however we take the derivative of $F(r,t)$ w.r.t r we yield $$C_{1}F^{'}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}=C_{2} - C_{3}F(r,t)$$ where $F^{'}$ is the derivative with respect to $r$..which is still entirely unhelpful without knowing more information about r.

Comment: @Chinny84 $r$ is just a variable, it ranges from $0\ldots \infty$. It is independent of $t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear first order ODE and you can use the [integrating factor method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). I.e. write your equation in the standard form

$$
\frac{d}{dt}F(r, t) + \frac{C_3}{C_1}F(r, t) = \frac{C_2}{C_1}
$$

and find the integrating factor $p$ from the coefficient of $F(r,t)$:

$$ p = \exp\left(\int \frac{C_3}{C_1} \;dt\right) = \exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right)$$

then multiply through by $p$ to get

$$ \exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right)\frac{d}{dt} F(r,t) + \frac{C_3}{C_1}\exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right)F(r,t) = \frac{C_2}{C_1}\exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right) $$

and use the product rule for differentiation to write

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left[ \exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right)F(r,t) \right] = \frac{C_2}{C_1}\exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right) $$

you can then integrate w.r.t. $t$ to get

$$  \exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right)F(r,t) = \frac{C_2}{C_3}\exp\left(\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right) + D$$

where $D$ is a constant of integration possibly involving $r$. Simplification gives

$$ F(r,t) = \frac{C_2}{C_3} + D \exp\left(-\frac{C_3}{C_1}t\right)$$

Of course, you can plug this back into your original equation as a check.